# Exception has occurred: ImportError cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am facing import error in this code please help me out it is in label map utility function i dint need code to fix it i need how to solve this import error.

```
"""Label map utility functions."""

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import collections
import logging
import sys
sys.path.append('models/research/object_detection')
import numpy as np
from six import string_types
from six.moves import range
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format
import object_detection
from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put that files in the same folder and just write

```
import string_int_label_map_pb2
```

instead of

```
from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
```

Also make sure you have converted protos files to .py file.